# Huggingface tokenizer - is there a way to identify it is cased or uncased

Tags: python, huggingface-tokenizers

Is there a way to know if the huggingface model tokenizer is case sensitive or not? For instance, [all-MiniLM-L6-v2](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L12-v2) is case insensitive.

```
sentence_all_minilm_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(f'sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
sentence_all_minilm_tokenizer
-----
BertTokenizerFast(name_or_path='sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2', vocab_size=30522, model_max_length=512, is_fast=True, padding_side='right', truncation_side='right', special_tokens={'unk_token': '[UNK]', 'sep_token': '[SEP]', 'pad_token': '[PAD]', 'cls_token': '[CLS]', 'mask_token': '[MASK]'}, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)
```

```
tokens_titled = sentence_all_minilm_tokenizer("Madame")['input_ids']
tokens_titled_decoded = sentence_all_minilm_tokenizer.batch_decode(tokens_titled)
print(f"Madame: tokens:{tokens_titled} decoded: {tokens_titled_decoded}")

tokens_small = sentence_all_minilm_tokenizer("madame".lower())['input_ids']
tokens_small_decoded = sentence_all_minilm_tokenizer.batch_decode(tokens_small)
print(f"madame: tokens:{tokens_small} decoded: {tokens_small_decoded}")
-----
Madame: tokens:[101, 10602, 102] decoded: ['[CLS]', 'madame', '[SEP]']
madame: tokens:[101, 10602, 102] decoded: ['[CLS]', 'madame', '[SEP]']
```

[gtr-t5-large](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/gtr-t5-large) is case sensitive and generates different results based on the case.

```
sentence_t5_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(f'sentence-transformers/gtr-t5-large')
sentence_t5_tokenizer
-----
T5TokenizerFast(name_or_path='sentence-transformers/gtr-t5-large', vocab_size=32100, model_max_length=512, is_fast=True, padding_side='right', truncation_side='right', special_tokens={'eos_token': '</s>', 'unk_token': '<unk>', 'pad_token': '<pad>',...
```

```
tokens_titled = sentence_t5_tokenizer("Madame")['input_ids']
tokens_titled_decoded = sentence_t5_tokenizer.batch_decode(tokens_titled)
print(f"Madame: tokens:{tokens_titled} decoded: {tokens_titled_decoded}")

tokens_small = sentence_t5_tokenizer("madame".lower())['input_ids']
tokens_small_decoded = sentence_t5_tokenizer.batch_decode(tokens_small)
print(f"madame: tokens:{tokens_small} decoded: {tokens_small_decoded}")
-----
Madame: tokens:[27328, 1] decoded: ['Madame', '</s>']
madame: tokens:[11454, 265, 15, 1] decoded: ['mad', 'am', 'e', '</s>']
```

HuggingFace model card e.g. [gtr-t5-large](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/gtr-t5-large) does not tell. Then, how to know if the text data for the model should be cased or uncased?